# How to put dependency on an input field if another is filled in?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a form like:

```
<form>
<ol>
<li>
<input class=identities name=ids[]>
<input class=names name=names[]>
</li>
<li>
<input class=identities name=ids[]>
<input class=names name=names[]>
</li>
</ol>
<input type=submit>
</form>
```

And I want `<input class=identities name=ids[]>` to have the [required attribute](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-input-element-attributes.html#the-required-attribute) set, only if the accompanying names field is not empty. I'm not sure how to express this in Javascript.

Comment: Write JavaScript for the submit button click event that checks the length of the text in the desired field. If that text length is greater than zero, then the length of the text in the dependent field must also be zero. Otherwise, return false.

Comment: @Zenith the check needs to happen on submit or right before submit, not onload. If you do it on submit, the problem is the validation has already been fired by that point.

Comment: @MrCode Ahh, of course :) OP should probably show us what he's tried, the question is kinda just asking for the whole thing..

Answer (score 0):

Solved using Jquery like so:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#submit").on("click", function() {
        $("li").each(function() {
            if ($(this).find('.names').val()) {
                $(this).find('.identities').attr('required', true)
            } else {
                $(this).find('.identities').attr('required', false)
        }
        });
})
})
```

If the right field classed "names" is filled in, then we set the `required` attribute on the left field.